# How to render options in react-select without setTimeout?

Tags: react-select

We are using react-select with Async options. In ui always we getting 'loading...' text before getting the result for search string. If we remove setTimeout options are not loaded. So how can we render options without setTimeut.

```
getOptions = (input, callback) => {
  this.props.searchSymbols(input);
  setTimeout(() => {
    const results = [];
    const { symbolList } = this.state;
    if (symbolList.length > 0) {
      Object.keys(symbolList).map(index => {
        const symbolObj = {};
        symbolObj.value = symbolList[index].symbolid;
        symbolObj.instrumenttypename = symbolList[index].instrumenttypename;
        symbolObj.exchangeid = symbolList[index].exchangeid;
        symbolObj.label = symbolList[index].shortname;
        results.push(symbolObj);
        return results;
      });
    }
    callback(null, {
      options: results
    });
  }, 500);  
};
```

Comment: Please share your code, btw the `setTimeout` is just an example of an async function, you have to replace it by your api request.

Comment: uploaded my code above. I have tried without timeout its not working properly. Options not loaded immediately if we remove setTimeout.

Comment: I suppose `searchSymbols` fetches the `symbolList` then pass it to your component state. Can you show some more code about this, if `searchSymbols` returns a `Promise` you can `.then()` it in place of setTimeout.

Comment: Thank you @Dyo. Its working, We have tried with `.then()` for `searchSymbols` its working fine now.